# Adding XML data at specific location

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a very large  XML data that should be loaded everytime the program starts.

```
<Calculation>
 <CalcGroup TypeOfGroup="GeneralInfo">
   <Parameter Name="name"></Parameter>
 </CalcGroup>
 <EnvironmetData>
  <EnvDataGroup  Id="1">
    <Parameter Name="Lastname"/>
  </EnvDataGroup>
 </EnvironmentData>
 <ComponentData>
  <Component TypeofComponent="Piston" ID="1">
   <ComponentCatagory="Values">
    <Parameter Name ="Temprature"></Parameter>
   </ComponentCatagory>
  </Component>
 </ComponentData>
</Calculation>
```

how to load the default XML ? and add or delete items in my project?

Whenever I tried to add an element for ex.

```
   Component com = new Componet();
   com.setTypeofComponent=("Piston");
   com.setID(BigInteger.valueof(2));
   ComponentData.getcomponet().add(com);
```

And i found this component added at the end of the XML file, whereas I need it just in the pistion catagory. fyi, I used jaxb to generate the property methods. And I am using this xml inside a java code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

**Add to End**

This is what you are currently doing.  The `add` method will add the new `Component` to the end of the `List` property.

```
componentData.getComponent().add(com);  // Add to End
```

**Add in Specific Position**

You can use the `List` APIs to add the new Component at a `specify` position.

```
componentData.getComponent().add(3, com);
```

**Modify Existing Item**

If you want to modify an existing `Component` from the `List` first you will need to access it.

```
Component com = componentData.getComponent().get(6);
com.setTypeofComponent=("Piston");
com.setID(BigInteger.valueof(2));
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. This is just what I needed. Adding to a specific location works perfect, now working on modifying.